# Is it recommended to utilise the Hadoop Ecosystems parallel processing to manage and maintain slowly changing data warehouse dimensions?

Tags: hadoop, etl, data-warehouse, data-processing

We have transactional hourly data and daily bulk loaded data from operational systems which we engineer into data warehouse dimensions (and facts) in a MS SQL Server environment. If recommended, what fast and efficient techniques (Flume, Sqoop, Kafka, HDFS, HBase, Hive, KUDU, Spark, Impla) could we apply to achieve this in Hadoop? The assumption is that these dimensions would be consumed hourly by the MS SQL Server data warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

a possible option is Nifi or MiniFi

https://nifi.apache.org/